# How to create the Numpy array X of shape (2638, 1838) for a dataframe has shape (2638, 1840)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

[image]

[image]

Hi, can someone please help me with this? What should do if I want to use NumPy to get an array X which has a shape (2638, 1838) while the dataframe has a shape of (2638, 1840)?

Here is my code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df = pd.read_csv('pbmc_data.csv', index_col = 0)
    df.shape
```

Comment: number of column is 1840 in which contain index column and y column, remove this column you will get shape of 1838, once you have pandas dataframe just use df.to_numpy() to convert it into numpy array

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion to *Numpy* and back to *Pandas*, as advised in one of
comments to your post, is not any elegant solution.
Fortunately, *Pandas* is able to do your tasks on its own.

Your first task is to select all columns of the input *df*
except for 2 last columns (*cell_type* and *cell_type_string*).
To do it, run:

```
X = df.iloc[:, :-2]
```

The second task is to extract the last but one column (second
from the end). To do it, run:

```
y = df.iloc[:, -2]
```